# Supervisor apparently making it appear that our team underperformed and we indirectly caused client not to pay full

Tags: management, performance-reviews, performance, philippines

Since I posted my question about how to leave my contract because I was inconsistently paid, I have sought other jobs below radar. The following events have happened:

My colleagues came to me with complaints of their pay getting delayed as well. It was a relief, to be honest. My company expressly forbids employees from discussing when their salaries will arrive. But with financial hardships for us looming at our doorstep, that rule is hard to follow.

Then one of my coworkers complained that our managers docked his wages for the past month because they thought he was no longer working for us. He argued, showing us his reports and emails, that it isn't true. He has resigned, and is still waiting for his back pay.

My coworker concluded that our managers would probably look for the slightest excuse not to pay us properly.

Later that day, our manager has explained to us that they had little money to pay us because the client refuses to pay them, because they think the module was improperly done. I'm guessing that whoever spoke with the client, they used improper ways to gather the software requirements for that module, thus there was a lot of misunderstanding.

The module was not done according to the client's requirements for that sprint. Our supervisor, the other manager, apparently wants to shift the blame on our team. Blame us for the financial trouble.

Admittedly, our team isn't perfect. We had delays. But we have completed many stories ahead of time too. The module was passed on time, and it was satisfactory to our QAs. Our supervisor also does tests before the client gets a copy. But then she hasn't tested the module properly. So it's hard to take her comments on our work seriously when she herself does not complete all her tests. I find it incredulous on her part to assume that we--the team--did not deliver all features properly. We were also asking for documentation for all the mistakes the client saw. So far, nothing was given to us.

Let me be clear that I am still leaving this company. I'm going to starve if I don't. Besides, she has been rude to us recently, me included. She does not reply to any of my messages anymore. Our manager has at least apologized to us about the inconsistent pay and has given me a flattering recommendation on LinkedIn. But not my supervisor. I'm done with her.

What can I do about this? I mean besides simply leaving and demanding that they pay me? Is my supervisor really undervaluing our performance so they would have an excuse to pay us improperly? Can I call out my supervisor on this? Is there really nothing I can do about her behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you are willing to go the legal route and Sue for unpaid wages, or leave an anonymous negative review of the company somewhetre, there really is nothing you can do.

Comment: In what jurisdiction are you in? Have you spoken to a lawyer? Are you really a contractor and not an employee? Usually, contractors have less rights than employees. But you should still talk to someone about this.

Comment: @keshlam I can't risk leaving a negative review without being found out, not until I get my pay and my certificate of employment anyway.

Comment: Then don't. It probably wouldn't do any good anyway. Lat leaves you with the choices of going to court or writing it off as a learning experience. Pick one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What can I do about this? I mean besides simply leaving and demanding that they 
>   pay me?

Yes. With a lawyer.

> Is my supervisor really undervaluing our performance so they would have an 
>   excuse to pay us improperly?

You know what this is called? FRAUD. It does not matter whether you worked good or bad, you earned your pay. That is the law. If the employer is not happy with your performance he can fire you post factum, or renegotiate for the future. But as employee you owe work hours, ethically done. If that is not good enough, if shit happens - that is not your problem. Except for gross neglect, not showing up, stealing, sabotage and other such things you owe the money your contract states.